# Upgraded mysql from 5.0 to 5.1, now Rails 2.3 is broken (on Mac)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I upgraded mysql on my Mac from 5.0.x to 5.1.x (using a dmg package directly from mysql.com), which broke Rails (2.3.2). Previously everything was working correctly. The error I get is this:

**!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.**

So I tried re-installing the mysql gem, tried uninstalling and reinstalling, still no luck. (Command used to install: 'sudo gem install mysql -- --with-my-sql-config=*PATH TO mysql_config on my machine*'. The gem installs fine, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Did a lot of digging on the web, and couldn't find a solution that sounded right. There were some suggestions for Windows of copying an older mysql dll, so there may be some Mac analogue, but that just sounds wrong to me.

Anybody else hit this problem?

Comment: I tried totally uninstalling mysql 5.1 (per these directions: http://akrabat.com/2008/09/11/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) and the mysql gem, then reinstalling 5.0 and the mysql gem. Still the same error. As far as I can tell, I have the same setup I had that was was working before the 5.1 upgrade, but something is still broken. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted out what the problem was that was causing the 'bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2' error. If you read this entry in my blog (http://freevirusesandspyware.com/2009/05/upgrading-ruby-on-mac-os-x-leopard-from.html) you'll see my saga of updating ruby from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 and the issues it caused with my gems. Well, I fixed those for my user account, but not for when I used sudo--they give different lists of installed gems when I do 'gem environment'/'sudo gem environment'. Ran the old gem tool and got the same list with and without sudo. Hmmm. So I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the mysql gem with the old gem tool, and bam! problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have used `sudo gem install mysql`?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. I did do sudo gem install.